# applying a managed meta-data column to a content type vs adding it to a view

Tags: document-library, content-type, managed-metadata

Hello this is my first question on here so please be gentle.

i have just provisioned a new document content type called GCDocument (whose parent is document) along with some new fields, such as a couple of choice fields and a managed meta data field.

I have added the choice fields to the content type.

This content type has then been added into a document library as the managed content type. So that when the user uploads a document they have to fill out the required fields.

My question is this.

Is the managed meta data field better added to the content type or just added to a view? or is it subjective which way i go about adding it?

if i need to clarify anything or have not been clear i am happy to elaborate.

many thanks in advance

Nicholas